# TeamExplorerEverywhere (TEE) eclipse plugin opens browser

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Oxygen with TFS 2013 and have installed TeamExplorerEverywhere plugin for working with the TFS repository. Whenever I try to create or open a work item it tries to do it with the web browser (IE of course...).

How do I make it open the work item open within Eclipse. I haven't seen anything in the preferences that could help.

I have just installed Oxygen as previously I work with Eclipse Kepler and the old TFS plugin opened everything within Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm afraid this is by designed for now (version 14.123.1):

> **The browser based work item editor replaced with an External Web
>   Browser.**
>
> *Source Link: [team-explorer-everywhere Release](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases)*

For old version, there has been a Embedded work item Editor, you could right click the work item and select open with, take a look at this [blog](https://ssinghvi.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/determine-the-url-of-a-work-item-from-visual-studioeclipse/).

Actually, open work items in a web browser window is also a trend now. In the newly Visual Studio Version, the default behavior is also opening from web directly. This brings many benefits. If you are interested, add some threads for your reference:

- [Work items now open in the web from Visual Studio ’15’](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/08/22/work-items-now-open-in-the-web-from-visual-studio-15/)
- [Work Item only in web](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28329/work-item-only-in-web.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately due to the nature of my work environment this is problematic. However, since I have Visual Studio 13 I can still create work items from there.